# How to scroll to center of HorizontalScrollView only when activity starts?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have a activity that shows a howizontalscrollview with a horizontally long imageview.

I need that when the activity starts, the horizontalscrollview must be scrolled to the center of itselft, and not to the start.

I'm searching on google and here and i can't find the way..

this is my horizontal scroll view:

```
    HorizontalScrollView wvScroll = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
    wvScroll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); 
    iv.setImageBitmap(Util.getRemoteImage("http://mywebsite.com/90.gif"));
    iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    wvScroll.addView(iv);
    mainLayout.addView(wvScroll);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
wvScroll.scrollTo(offsetX, 0);
```

There may be a timing issue, where the offset will be set before the scrollView is created. In that case, use `postDelayed()` with a `runnable` that calls `scrollTo`

ADDED:

To use postDelayed():

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

in onCreate do:

```
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
       wvScroll.scrollTo(offsetX, 0);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: i know scrollTo exists..... but..... how can i obtain that offsetX???? i didn't understand your way. Please, can you post a code example?

Comment: @Pableras84 - how about `offsetX = wvScroll.getWidth()/2`?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure but probably you need to have height and width of child. Smth like that:

```
int centerX = wvScroll.getChildAt(0).getWidth()/2;
int centerY = wvScroll.getChildAt(0).getHeight()/2;
wvScroll.scrollTo(centerX, centerY);
```